# ANTLR grammar returning java method name which can be executed using java compiler

Tags: java, compilation, antlr, antlr3

I have the below ANTLR grammar:

```
tree grammar findApp;

options {
    tokenVocab=TSRTemplate;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
    backtrack=true;
}


@header {
}

@members {

}

prog returns [String value]
        : ^(ROOT f=formula) {$value = $f.value; }
        ;

formula returns [String value]
        : ^(DEFINITION INTEGER t=calc_expr) {$value = $t.value;}
        ;

calculation_expr returns [String value]
@init {
    $value = null;
}
    : calculation_unit {$value = $calculation_unit.value;}
    | ^(PLUS n1=calculation_expr n2=calculation_expr) {
        $value="addApproach(<calculation_expr1>, <calculation_expr2>)";
    }
    ;

calc_unit returns [String value]
    : cf_expr {$value = $cf_expr.value;}
    ;

cf_expr returns [String value]
    :  ^(GET_APP string_expr)
    {
        $value = "getApp("+$STRING.text + ")";
    }
    ;
```

What I need to achieve is as below:

For example, the below grammar:

```
cf_expr returns [String value]
    :  ^(GET_APP string_expr)
    {
        $value = "getApp("+$STRING.text + ")";
    }
    ;
```

will return `getApp(<some parameter>)`, which is a method name.

This method is implemented in a java class (Method.java),

I want my grammar to return this method name and compile this java class (Method.java) and execute the method implementation in this class.

Any suggestions on how to integrate java class compiling with ANTLR will be helpful.

Comment: Well, that's not how the things work. There're at least three things involved in your requirements: the grammar, the Java compiler, and an executor (a JVM). ANTLR can help you only with the first one. It can create a parse tree for you using the grammar you provide, and that's it. For anything else you have to write code on your own (or use other libraries). Read about visitor or listener patterns and write java code that will traverse the generated tree, find the required information, compile the file and execute it.

Comment: Is there a way to write a translator with "output=template" and each grammar returns a function which can be executed as a java method? Is StringTemplate used only when you want to execute the implementation in another language? i.e. if I am executing grammar from java,does it make sense to use a StringTemplate which executes a java method in another class?